# Cant draw two-dimensional array, pygame

Tags: arrays, pygame, 2d

I am currently trying create grid of boxes with pygame. My code here is below and I just cant seem to be able to figure this one out. My goal here is to have pygame draw out 100 rectangles.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("2D Grid")




screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

RED = (255, 0, 0)

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

w = 60

grid = [[n]*10 for n in range(10)]
print grid

def drawGrid():

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            pygame.Rect(x , y, w, w)
            x = x + w
        y = y + w
        x = 0

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, drawGrid())
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it was quite simple after all.

def drawGrid():

```
x = 0
y = 0
for row in grid:
    for col in row:
        box = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, w)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, box)
        pygame.Surface.blit(screen, space_img, box)
        x = x + w
    y = y + w
    x = 0
```

and I tried to call the drawing function whilst trying to draw the rectangles. So I simply tried to call the function and of course that worked. :)